# how to get variable on managed-bean?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am trying to make a login screen, so I get ıbanNumber and pass from user and check it on the database. This is working but when I try to use `doldur() on another page for fetch some info on database with the same ıbanNumber it returns null.

How can I fix this situation and why does ibanNumber return null ?

not: add jsf page when ı click "hesap işlemleri" button on the "Kullanici İslem Menusu.xhtml" page then  open "hesap işlemleri.xhtml" and fill the dataTable

```
@ManagedBean(name = "login")

public class LoginBean {

public LoginBean() {

}
private String ıban_number;
private String sifre;
private String paraCek;
private String paraYatir;


public String getParaCek() {
    return paraCek;
}

public void setParaCek(String paraCek) {
    this.paraCek = paraCek;
}

public String getParaYatir() {
    return paraYatir;
}

public void setParaYatir(String paraYatir) {
    this.paraYatir = paraYatir;
}

public String getIban_number() {
    return ıban_number;
}

public void setIban_number(String ıban_number) {
    this.ıban_number = ıban_number;
}

public String getSifre() {
    return sifre;
}

public void setSifre(String sifre) {
    this.sifre = sifre;
}
db_connection dbLogin = new db_connection();
private PreparedStatement psLogin;
private ResultSet rsLogin;

public String getLogin() {


    try {

        System.out.println(getIban_number() + " " + getSifre());
        psLogin = dbLogin.getCon().prepareStatement("select * from kullanici_giris where ibanNumber=? and sifre=?");
        psLogin.setString(1, getIban_number());
        psLogin.setString(2, getSifre());
        System.out.println("Veri tabanına ulaşıldı");
        rsLogin = psLogin.executeQuery();

        while (rsLogin.next()) {
            return "true";

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return "false";
}

public List<getAccountInfo> doldur() {

    System.out.println(getIban_number());
    List<getAccountInfo> liste = new ArrayList<getAccountInfo>();
    try {
        psLogin = dbLogin.getCon().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM hesap_bilgi where ibanNumber = ? ");
        psLogin.setString(1, getIban_number());
        rsLogin = psLogin.executeQuery();


        while (rsLogin.next()) {
            getAccountInfo obj = new getAccountInfo();

            obj.setIbanNumber(rsLogin.getString(1));
            obj.setToplamButce(rsLogin.getString(2));
            obj.setHarcananButce(rsLogin.getString(3));
            obj.setKalanButce(rsLogin.getString(4));


            liste.add(obj);


        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }


    return liste;
}
}




    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Kullanici İslem Menusu</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">

                <h:commandButton value="Hesap İşlemleri" action="hesap_islemleri"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Kişisel İşlemleri" action="kisisel_islemler"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Şubelerimiz" action="subelerimiz"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>



<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>


            <h:dataTable value="#{login.doldur()}" var="c">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="ıbanNumber"/>

                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{c.ibanNumber}"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="ToplamButce"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{c.toplamButce}"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="HarcananButce"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{c.harcananButce}"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="KalanButce"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{c.kalanButce}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: `System.out.println(getIban_number());` Does this print the expected value ?

Comment: Please show the JSF code in the page where this fails.

Comment: ıt's print Null; but System.out.println(getIban_number() + " " + getSifre()); this print what ı expected.

Comment: what is the scope of your managed Bean ?

Comment: thanks for your help. I add @SessionScoped and implements Serializable it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Your iBanNumber is passed from the user and stored in the instance of the bean that is initialized when running the first page. When you call it from another page, a new instance is created of your managed bean. Maybe that is why, the value you are setting in the bean the first time is no longer available the second time. Try changing the scope of the managed bean to SessionScoped. That way, the values in the bean are retained for the entire duration of the session. You can read more about the JSF sessions [here](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's strange the way you are getting the properties.

For example, if you have a managed bean (name="mBean") and a property "String property"; you have the getter and setter "getProperty" and "setProperty", ok?

So, when you call it from a xhtml page, by Expession Language, you will use, for example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{mBean.property}" />
```

---

So, 
 
1 - Is it really working the dataTable when you use doldur()? Don't you need something like the property "Collection doldur" and its getter and setter "getDoldur" and "setDoldur"?

2 - The same way of thinking ; don't you have to declare "String ıbanNumber", then you have the getter and setter "getIbanNumber" and "setIbanNumber" and then

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{c.ibanNumber}"/>
```

?

Check these things first!